# Same RGB but different color for cell, header background in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I have a headerView for a cell and a cell containing a collectionView. I wish to make both have a background color of

```
UIColor(red: 0.898, green: 0.898, blue: 0.898, alpha: 1.0)
```

I set both headerView's background color and the cell and its collectionView's background color with the color above. However, when I run the code, I get a little contrast in color between the headerView and the tableView cell. I'm not sure why. I used the same UIColor.

[image]

You can see the subtle difference.

Comment: Can you attach the full code of the Views configuration? Maybe you have other properties on the view itself that are different

Comment: You should set color by adding /255  like : `UIColor(red: 0.898/255, green: 0.898/255, blue: 0.898/255, alpha: 1.0)`

Comment: @Kudos No absolutely not. The values are already in between 0-1 range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to check out cell `contentView`, cells and its content views for your collection view.

If this still doesn't help, try [examining the view hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html) to check which view background wasn't changed.

Comment: Yes, the problem was that I was setting the cell's background's color. What I needed to do was set the cell's content view's background color instead.